# How to support multiple languages with cocos2d-x?

Tags: localization, cocos2d-x

I'm working in the development of a game with cocos2s-x which will be available for iOS, Android, QNX and Windows, for which the texts are being created with CCLabelBMFont. This ones must be in the same language of the device. Is there a way to do it with cocos2d-x ([this issue suggests it that way](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/323)) or should I program it natively in each case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As easy as use [CCApplication::getCurrentLanguage()](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/boards/6/topics/2951).